# Angular 6: Updating POST request from Http to HttpClient

Tags: angular-httpclient

I am upgrading my Angular Application from Angular 4 to 6 which means I am replacing `Http` with `HttpClient`. The POST request with Angular 4 worked perfectly fine but I am getting into some trouble with Angular 6.

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

    post(path: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = environment.api_url + '/' + path;
    return this.http.post(url,
      body
    )
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()), catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error.json())));
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public sendEnquiry() {
    this.sendingEnquiry = true;
    if (
        this.enquiry.college.length > 0 &&
        this.enquiry.university.length > 0 &&
        this.enquiry.official_email.length > 0 &&
        this.enquiry.official_person.length > 0 &&
        this.enquiry.user_name.length > 0 &&
        this.enquiry.user_email.length > 0 &&
        this.enquiry.user_type.length > 0
      ) {
      this.apiService.post('univinks/college_enquiry', this.enquiry)
      .subscribe( (res) => {
        console.log(res.message);
        this.showSuccessToast(res.message);
        this.sendingEnquiry = false;
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.showErrorToast('Some error occurred. Enquiry not sent');
        this.sendingEnquiry = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.showErrorToast('Incomplete Enquiry Form');
      this.sendingEnquiry = false;
    }
  }
```

This is working fine and as intended sends an email with the enquiry details to the user. The issue is that it shows the error toast *"Some error occurred. Enquiry not sent"* instead of showing the success toast and navigating to home route ' '. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems valid transformation, can you check more error details or create demo?

Comment: TypeError: t.json is not a function. This is what I get in console when I click on the button.